# Fault Message Format from asmx web service

Tags: c#

**strong text**
I have a basic web service (asmx) which throws soap exception. Below is the the         code of service.asmx and web.config. I am expecting the response from web         service in below format in IE. but i am getting the reponse with a single line         in IE as "this is exception".Can you please help me to get the format as given below. I am not able to         understand where to change?in any web.config file or asmx??

```
service.aspx
============  
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="zzz" %>

using System.Web.Services;

using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

using System.Xml;

[WebServiceBinding()]

public class zzz : WebService

{

[WebMethod()]

public void abc() 

{

throw new SoapException("this is the exception", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);

}

}

expecting the response as below
===============================
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Validation Exception</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ErrorCode>TESTCODE</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDescription>No matching emp information. Please change your request.</ErrorDescription>
     </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
```

```
web.xml
===============================
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
<!-- 
Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
affects performance, set this value to true only 
during development.
-->
<compilation debug="true"/>
<!--
The <authentication> section enables configuration 
of the security authentication mode used by 
ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
-->
<authentication mode="Windows"/>

<customErrors mode="On"/>

<!--
The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
it enables developers to configure html error pages 
to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
<error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
<error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
-->
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Attach what you see in IE please

Comment: Thomas, i am getting below message in IE. its only one line "this is the exception". but i need the format in my question

Comment: The answer is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/aa480514.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem can be in IE setting, specifically "show friendly http error messages" option.

Check with Fiddler the raw http output.

Comment: Thomas, i am getting below message in IE. its only one line "this is the exception". but i need the format in my question

Comment: Thomas, I enabled "show friendly http error messages" but i am getting the following erro in the screen. "The website cannot display the page" HTTP 500. I don;t know how to attache the screen shot.